# Ignore utm_* values with varnish?

Tags: caching, url-rewriting, varnish, varnish-vcl

Can I 'ignore' query string variables before pulling matching objects from the cache, but not actually remove them from the URL to the end-user?

For example, all the marketing `utm_source`, `utm_campaign`, `utm_*` values don't change the content of the page, they just vary a lot from campaign to campaign and are used by all of our client-side tracking.

So this also means that the URL can't change on the client side, but it should somehow be 'normalized' in the cache.

Essentially I want all of these...

`http://example.com/page/?utm_source=google`

`http://example.com/page/?utm_source=facebook&utm_content=123`

`http://example.com/page/?utm_campaign=usa`

... to all access HIT the cache for `http://example.com/page/`

However, this URL would cause a MISS (because the param is not a utm_* param)

`http://example.com/page/?utm_source=google&variation=5`

Would trigger the cache for

`http://example.com/page/?variation=5`

Also, keeping in mind that the URL the user sees must remain the same, I can't redirect to something without params or any kind of solution like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick... it's not perfect according to my own question though as it ignores ALL query params, not just utm ones. When I need to actually implement a non-utm value which changes the content I will need to revisit this regex:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*", "");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So I'll add a disclaimer that this regex probably isn't perfect, but it should work pretty well:

```
sub vcl_recv {  
  set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_[^=&]*=[^&=]*&?)+", "?");
  set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_[^=&]*=[^&=]*(&|$))+", "\2");
  set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");

  return (pass);
}
```

This should remove any query parameters starting with `utm_`. I used three regexs to make it clearer and easier to read.

The first `regsuball` removes any `utm_` parameters at the beginning of the query string. It looks for one or more `utm_` parameters immediately after the `?`. The second `regsuball` removes any `utm_` parameters that aren't at the beginning of the query string.

The third regex will cleanup the URL by removing the `?` if there are no query parameters left after we are done removing `utm_` parameters.

Both regexes need to be in `()+` as this will match one or more consecutive `utm_` parameters (they wouldn't be matched otherwise).

Example results:

```
Source URL: /?utm_track=1&utm_test2=hey&test=utm_blah&utm_source=google&variation=5&utm_query=abc&utm_test7=yes
Maps to:    /?test=utm_blah&variation=5

Source URL: /?variation=5&utm_test1=abc&utm_test2=def&blah=1
Maps to:    /?variation=5&blah=1
```

Comment: This `[^&=]` won't handle `utm_` parameters that have `=` signs in them (imagine `?utm_track=foo=bar`, I believe. = signs are legal in the query portion of URIs even though web forms usually escape them. Someone (or an ad network) forging a UTM laden URI might not. I would replace `[^&=]` with `[^&]` since you want to remove the entire query param up until the next query param.

Comment: The Varnish documentation [recommends against](https://book.varnish-software.com/3.0/VCL_Basics.html#default-vcl-recv) `pass`ing out of a user-defined `vcl-recv` function. Given the request lifecycle, the `pass` looks like it will also skip cache lookup--why not overwrite `req.url` and let the lookup continue like normal without returning?